# matlab for (decreasing) in C

Tags: c, matlab, for-loop

How can I convert a matlab for to C language?

Matlab:

```
for i = 1:l,
    for a = d:-1:2,
        mem(a) = mem(a-1);
    end;
    mem(1) = s(i);
    y(i) = a0*mem(1) + a1*mem(d0) + a2*mem(d);
end;
```

C (that's what I did, but it seems not working):

```
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        for (j=d; j==2; j--) {
                mem[j]=mem[j-1];
        }
        mem[0]=x[i];
        y[i]= a0*mem[0]+a1*mem[d0]+ a2*mem[d];
    }
```

Is my conversion correct?

Comment: In the first loop the condition has to be `i <= l` (since in Matlab the vector 1:l takes both 1 and l). In the second the condition has to be `j>=2` since you are decreasing from d to 2 in steps of -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my conversion correct?

No, see below.

`for` loops always have a form like

```
for (FROM; WHILE; NEXT) BODY
```

and are executed like:

1. evaluate the *FROM* expression (usually initialization)
2. evaluate the *WHEN* expression

   - if it is true, goto 3
   - else, exit the loop
3. then evaluate the *BODY*
4. evaluate *NEXT* (usually advancing the iteration)
5. goto 2

Note that the conditional is always a *while*, and never an *until*. They're logically opposites.

Now, look at your two loops:

```
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
```

runs *while* `i < 1`. As soon as that condition is false, the loop exits.

```
for (j=d; j==2; j--)
```

You *want* this to loop *until* `j==2`, but that's not how `for` loops work. It actually loops *while* `j==2`, which is to say, never. It should be

```
for (j=d; j >= 2; j--)
```

Comment: only that the first loop works while i < l (variable L, not 1). In my comment there was already the correct answer.

Comment: Also the second loop has to work until j==2 including the value 2, so the operator should be `>=` instead of `>`.

Comment: Apparently we were writing at the same time. If you have the answer, why not submit an answer instead of commenting?